# How to register JavaScript helpers with Handlebars.net

Tags: javascript, helper, handlebars.net

How would we register these two JavaScript helpers in Handlebars.Net?

**For Moment.js:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatDate", function (datetime, format) {
    return moment(datetime).format(format);
});
```

**For a java script calculation:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatPercent", function (val1, limit) {
    return Math.ceil(100 * val1 / limit);
});m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [readme](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net) gives an example for how to write helpers:

```
Handlebars.RegisterHelper("link_to", (writer, context, parameters) => {
  writer.WriteSafeString("<a href='" + context.url + "'>" + context.text + "</a>");
});

string source = @"Click here: {{link_to}}";

var template = Handlebars.Compile(source);

var data = new {
    url = "https://github.com/rexm/handlebars.net",
    text = "Handlebars.Net"
};

var result = template(data);

/* Would render:
Click here: <a href='https://github.com/rexm/handlebars.net'>Handlebars.Net</a>
*/
```

The most important difference is in .NET, the helper doesn't return a value. Rather, you're given a reference to the `TextWriter` that is generating the template output. So your helper can write whatever it wants directly to the template via that writer. There is a `.WriteSafeString()` helper included to bypass the default encoding. **Make sure your string is actually safe to not encode when you do that.**

Comment: my main concern was how how to call java script functions from within handlebars.net

Comment: for example how do you use moment.js in handlebars.net

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu handlebars.net is not a bridge to running Javascript. It is still plain .NET. So you cannot call javascript functions from it, any more than you could call javascript from any other part of .NET, unless you use an emulator or some other engine.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. This example sheds some light https://gist.github.com/rexm/e1a045b9f76a48de642e

```
    Handlebars.RegisterHelper("formatDate", New HandlebarsHelper(Sub(w, c, p)
                                                                     w.WriteSafeString("moment(" + p(0) + ").format(" + p(1) + ");")
                                                                 End Sub))

    Handlebars.RegisterHelper("formatPercent", New HandlebarsHelper(Sub(w, c, p)
                                                                        If p(1) = 0 Then
                                                                            w.WriteSafeString("0")
                                                                        Else
                                                                            w.WriteSafeString("Math.ceil(" + 100 * p(0) / p(1) + ");")
                                                                        End If
                                                                    End Sub))
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. This will simply print the string "moment(p1).format(p2)" into the output of the template.